# What is this large plant with spikes of hot pink bracts, growing in South Africa?

Tags: identification

What is this large plant with spikes of hot pink bracts and lavender, trumpet shaped flowers, that's growing in South Africa?

[image: This photo was taken mid-April in the Southern hemisphere, so Autumn.]

This photo was taken mid-April in the Southern hemisphere, so Autumn. It's about 2m tall, growing in full sun, and is in Pretoria, South Africa.

Comment: http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-1729225-stock-footage-tropical-flowering-shrub-family-acanthaceae.html  This video looks like it might be the same plant.  It is the family Acanthaceae, but the species is not shown.  I will continue to look.

Comment: http://resources2.news.com.au/images/2011/04/02/1226032/491130-brazilian-red-cloak-megaskepasma-erythrochlamys.jpg This looks about right.  It is the Brazilian Red Cloak, Megaskepasma Erythrochlamys of the Acanthaceae family.  What do you folks think?

Comment: http://pics.davesgarden.com/pics/2005/01/27/giancarlo/210676.jpg This image pretty much confirms it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ca. they call it a [shrimp plant, *Justicia brandegeeana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justicia_brandegeeana).

Comment: That does look similar, but I haven't seen one that size, or with that long of flowers. Not that they grow here outdoors, but...

Comment: This is a good answer!  It looks very similar, but I have also not seen a shrimp plant grow that tall, or have such big leaves, or such long bracts.  It might be related, and this might be a good starting point to find out what the plant actually is.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, because it's the only answer, and, because of this I was able to find the family name of the shrimp plant, and look for other species within that family, which led to me identifying the plant.  Sometimes being put on the right path is the best answer one can hope for :)

Comment: @RichieACC Better yet, If you were led to the right name, (which I think you were) it will be helpful to post a self-answer, and accept that. That way when folks find this question, it will have an official and correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you've already found, this is actually [*Megaskepasma Erythrochlamys*](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=e966), or Brazilian Red Cloak, not a shrimp plant, *Justicia brandegeana*. This plant is native to Venezuela.

Here's, a comparison pic, from [here](http://www.devonstorknursery.com.au/gallery4.php):

[image]